# Excel pivot value filter only show blanks

Tags: excel, pivot

I have combined 2 different tables to understand which courses are missing at each location. I have identified which courses are missing by looking at what is available at each location (Table1) and comparing it against (official list). It has generated below overview.

[excel image of pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfbRX.png)

I want to only see the courses that are missing at each location. Above you can see that the RED are the missing courses, but how do i filter out the (1) from the overview. When i try to use "Value filters" (less than 1) function none is displayed as the (0) are only visible because i have chosen to show (0) whenever there is a blank value (Pivot table settings).

Hence how do i either only filter on blank values in the value filter or replace the "Blanks" in the pivot table?

thank you in advance